# How "Eyeball Glide Ball" toy works?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium, stability

How this toy works? As you roll the ball on the table, the eye always point up:

[image]

(original video source: https://youtu.be/_3kAjWaxM30)

As far I am aware, no magnets are involved in the construction of this toy.

Comment: Kind of off topic. But, a brief Google hunt turns up suggestions that these things have been discontinued because the contents are grossly toxic when ingested. Apparently, many kids had the same question you do, opened them, and got very ill.  Sadly, I didn't find any info on what exactly is in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably something like this, where the weight is fixed to the inner sphere (the thickness of the blue layer is exaggerated):
[image]

Since the inner sphere is free to rotate, the point opposed to the weight will always point up.